# How to pass blob url to rails create method by ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want to upload a voice sound in my Rails project.
The recording works fine to download, but I can't send the data to rails server.

```
recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function (blob) {
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        console.log(url);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/voices",
            data: {voice: {sound: url}}
        });
    });
```

In server log there is a post data, but `sound` was not created.

```
Started POST "/voices" for ::1 at 2015-12-08 20:43:16 +0900
Processing by VoicesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"voice"=>{"sound"=>"blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3000/3ad3859e-b960-44b8-ba18-20727e739bab"}}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Profile Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "voices" ("sound", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["sound", nil], ["created_at", "2015-12-08 11:43:16.254713"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-08 11:43:16.254713"]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 135ms (ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)
```

How can I pass the sound blob data to rails server?

#### voices_controller.rb

```
class VoicesController < ApplicationController
    @voice = Voice.new(voice_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @voice.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'voice was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: root_path }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @voice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  def voice_params
    params.require(:voice).permit(:sound, :user_id)
  end
end
```

#### app/models/voice.rb

```
class Voice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :phrase
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :sound, SoundUploader
end
```

### Another attempt

```
recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function (blob) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    console.log(url);

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('voice[sound]', url);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/voices",
        data: formData
    });
});
```

This codes ends up with a error `Uncaught TYpeError: Illegal invocation`.

Comment: Your Controller code is not available and looking at the logs I am guessing that while saving the model, you are not passing the sound along to be saved.

Comment: `Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 135ms (ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)` could you attach the error message?

Comment: I added the controller. Am I saving wrongly?

Comment: @richfisher That was because I forgot to add a corresponding view template, there is any more `500 Internal Server Error`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, if you are trying to post the data correctly or have your models setup properly.  you need to save your audio as a file, using File.open(filename, w)

```
    SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "voices" ("sound", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["sound", nil], ["created_at", "2015-12-08 11:43:16.254713"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-08 11:43:16.254713"]]
```

The SQL, is suggesting, that nothing is getting passed to "sound" field.

1. if you are passing it as a blob, you need to set the column accordingly, if not done entirely, however better option would be 2)
2. Send and save the audio data as a file.  Have a look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801268/save-audio-file-in-rails)

   ```
   formData.append('voice[sound]', url); # Comment this
   formData.append('voice[sound]', blob); # This will send the actual data to your server and not the blob url. then your carrierwave will have the file data, which it can save.
   ```

Comment: Sorry, that I didn't write enough information. I'm using a carrierwave to handle files. I still can't get how to handle the binary files. I'm very thankful if you could help me.

Comment: have a look at the updated answer, you are sending a blob url, which only is existing in your browser, a better way should be to send the actual **blob** data to your rails application.

Comment: I changed the line, then I got `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` error. I'm stuck..

Comment: I guess, this is error with jQuery setting up headers incorrectly as processing the blob data, can you have a look at  [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax). you might need to add `processData: false` to your ajax call.

Comment: Finally! I just need to add `processData: false` and `contentType: false`, as the post that you showed me. Thanks!