# how to save a blob file using carrierwave in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So i have a requirement where i record a video and save it in the database, the recording of the video is working fine, only thing is it generates a blob file, then i use js to send the blob file to the server. This are my params

```
{"testqwe"=>{"attr"=>"blob:http://localhost:3000/6f12f123-b1d0-7bfc-6b15-d3b54341946"}, "controller"=>"myControler", "action"=>"test"}
```

i have an uploader in place , but it does not save anything.

so how can i save this using carierwave to my database?

here is my javascript

```
mediaRecorder.onstop = (ev) ->
        blob = new Blob(chunks, 'type': 'video/mp4;')
        chunks = []
        videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        vidSave.src = videoURL
        $.ajax
          type: 'POST'
          content_type: "video/webm"
          url: '/test'
          enctype: "multipart/form-data"
          data: testqwe: attr: videoURL
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

any one still trying to figure out this, u can refer this link

[How to pass blob url to rails create method by ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34155065/how-to-pass-blob-url-to-rails-create-method-by-ajax?lq=1)

```
mediaRecorder.onstop = (ev) ->
        blob = new Blob(chunks, 'type': 'video/mp4;')
        chunks = []
        videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        vidSave.src = videoURL

        formData = new FormData
        formData.append('testqwe[attr]', blob);

        $.ajax
          type: 'POST'
          url: '/test'
          processData: false
          contentType: false
          data: formData
        return
```

Send and save the audio/video data as a file